# Maximum value of complex valued function

Tags: complex-analysis, absolute-value

I need to find maximum value of the following complex valued function
\begin{align*}
\underset{-\pi\le x\le \pi}{\mathrm{max}}\left\vert x e^{-\mathrm{i}k x^2}\right\vert,\quad k\in \mathbb{R}^{+}.
\end{align*}
I do not know how to proceed.

Comment: This is a higly oscillating function. I need a general expression in the form of "k". The parameter "k" controls oscillations.

Comment: Remember that $\left| e^{it}\right|=1\quad \forall t\in\mathbb{R}.$

Comment: Thanks. If its that easy, I will not ask here. Thats little tricky.

Answer (score 2):

We know that

$$\forall t\in \Bbb R\;\;\; e^{it}=\cos (t)+i\sin (t) $$
and

$$|e^{it}|=\sqrt {\cos^2 (t)+\sin^2 (t)}=1$$

thus
$$|xe^{-ikx^2}|=|x| |e^{-ikx^2}|=|x|$$

the max is $\pi $.

Comment: Thanks. I did this way but thats not true. If you plot the function, you will know. As the oscillations increase so is the amplitude. The end points do not provide max value.

Comment: @skorpion can  you please provide an example where $$\left| x\exp\left(-ikx^2\right)\right| \ne |x|?$$